# PHP file size converter

Tags: php, file, converters

I need to convert random numbers into KB, MB, GB and TB. For example, if 2048 is generated, it needs to display as 2KB.

I am not sure where to start with this, except for generating a random number:

```
$number = rand(1,1000000);
echo $number;
```

Would really appreciate if someone pointed me to the right direction.

Comment: Do you want to generate random number or do you want to get the size of actual files and show there size?

Comment: _“Would really appreciate if someone pointed me to the right direction.”_ - typing something rather trivial like _“php display file size in kb mb”_ into Google easily finds the duplicate.

Comment: The thread got closed but I wanted to throw my suggestion that avoids multiple if statements and allows for easily adding more sizes if required; check out: https://3v4l.org/nY4V7

Comment: @CBroe glad typing trivial questions into Google works out for you but for me it didn't give me the result I wanted. Anything else?

Comment: @IsThisJavascript Thank you

Comment: Yes - please learn to research then, instead of using your lack of skills in that department as an excuse.

Comment: Yeah I'm with CBroe on this one :X. The search term I'd use for this question would be "convert sizes in php stackoverflow" which would lead to that duplicate. Hopefully you can learn to get better at google fu

Comment: @AnyaK You're being incredibly rude and that's going to hurt you when you come back to ask more questions on this site.

Comment: @IsThisJavascript just answering in the same style as the other person. People have to learn somehow and this site is supposed to help with that. Obviously, I am a noob at PHP and sometimes I don't know how to ask a question, whether it's here or google. That, however, doesn't give anyone the right to be snotty and rude to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `round()` and following may help you. I use this code in production for a long time.

```
function convert_bytes_to_hr_format($size){
    if (1024 > $size) {
        return $size.' B';
    } else if (1048576 > $size) {
        return round( ($size / 1024) , 2). ' KB';
    } else if (1073741824 > $size) {
        return round( (($size / 1024) / 1024) , 2). ' MB';
    } else if (1099511627776 > $size) {
        return round( ((($size / 1024) / 1024) / 1024) , 2). ' GB';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, sir! @Thamaraiselvam

Comment: Glad to help you, mark as answer if this answer fixed your problem. Happy coding.